# SQL Server not displaying currency symbol correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following encoding problem: In 2 databases I should have the same data (2nd database is newer version of 1st). In some tables, characters are not displaying correctly, such a currency table that holds the name and symbols for different currencies.
I use SSMS to query both databases.

```
Id  Name    R7  R8  Name    Different
-------------------------------------
148 DZD              DZD    0
 37 EGP     Â£  £    EGP    1
149 ERN              ERN    0
150 ETB              ETB    0
  1 EUR     â‚¬ €    EUR    1
 40 FJD     $   $    FJD    0
 39 FKP     Â£  £    FKP    1
  2 GBP     Â£  £    GBP    1
151 GEL              GEL    0
 46 GGP     Â£  £    GGP    1
 42 GHC     Â¢  ¢    GHC    1
152 GHS              GHS    0
```

Both tables(Currency) have the same structure and encoding for symbol col(R7 & R8): `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`. I have tried to look up encoding solutions, but have run out of ideas of what to ask in google.
Does anyone know what might cause R7 to display incorrectly while R8 displays correctly?

Column definition for R7 (ShortName):
[image]

Column definition for R8 (ShortName):
[image]

@AlwaysLearning :
[image]

Comment: db collation? ... Tables schema pls

Comment: Where are you seeing `£` displayed as `Â£`? Is this in SSMS or some other means of viewing the data?

Comment: The collation can also be set on column level, so check that too. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/set-or-change-the-column-collation?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Seems like your application is trying to store UTF-8 encoded data into a Code Page 1252-based column (ref: [SQL Server collations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-ver16#SQL-collations)). Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73194888/edit) your question to include the output of `select cast(R7 as varbinary(max)) from Currency where Id=37`.

Comment: So we can plainly see that the columns do NOT in fact contain the same values for the currency symbols. The UTF8 guess seems to be [correct](http://unicode.org/mail-arch/unicode-ml/y2009-m06/0069.html)

Comment: I'm guessing someone inserted the data wrongly in the first place, probably by injecting it into a query without using using the `N` prefix